# Carrying an ID with strings to a next page

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to carry the ID to the next page, but all i manage to get is review.php?ID= without the ID.

Here is the code:

```
html = html + "Name:" + name + "Type : " + type + "Location : " + location + '<input type="button" value="Write a review!" onclick=parent.location="review.php?ID=" ('+ ID +') />'  + "<br/>";
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things wrong here.  You have mismatched quotes (single and double), and I'm pretty sure the id shouldnt have spaces round it with parens. The embeded quotes need to be escaped, too

something like this:

```
html = html + "Name:" + name + "Type : " + type + "Location : " + location + 
"<input type='button' value='Write a review!' onclick='parent.location=\"review.php?ID=("+ID+")\" />"  + "<br/>";
```

Comment: Hi Stuart! Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately the code doesn't work, now the button is not showing up at all.

Comment: Hello again. I did settle for a simple link and it seems to be working fine: `html = html + "Name:" + name + "Type : " + type + "Location : " + location + '<a href="review.php?id='+ID+'">review this venue</a>' + "<br/>";` Thank you again for all your help.